# Ringtone leaks in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, memory-leaks

This is my `BroadcastReceiver`, it plays a ringtone at a given time (invoked through `AlarmManager`).

```
if (ACTION_FINISHED.equals(intent.getAction()) && PrefUtils.isRestPlaySound(context)) {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
        if (r != null) {
            r.play();
        }
    }
```

It plays the Ringtone but after leaving the activity I get a leak pointing to

```
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
```

The stack trace:

```
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157): A resource was acquired at attached stack     trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination     method 'release' not called
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at     dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at android.drm.DrmManagerClient.<init>    (DrmManagerClient.java:277)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at     android.media.Ringtone.checkValidDrmFile(Ringtone.java:301)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at     android.media.Ringtone.setUri(Ringtone.java:225)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at     android.media.RingtoneManager.getRingtone(RingtoneManager.java:651)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at     android.media.RingtoneManager.getRingtone(RingtoneManager.java:632)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at     workout.progression.service.RestTimerReceiver.onReceive(RestTimerReceiver.java:24)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2525)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:159)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1392)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
05-20 10:50:43.652: E/StrictMode(16157):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**What is leaking and how do I stop it from leaking?**

Comment: Are you sure its about Ringtone? Please attach full StrictMode stacktrace

Comment: Ive attached the whole strack trace.

Comment: I believe this is framework side issue in particular device. What device are you using?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the code Ive given in the question internally creates a `MediaPlayer` instance, and not calling `MediaPlayer.release` was the thing triggering the leak.

My solution was to create and use a MediaPlayer myself and calling release on it after playback was finished.

```
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, sRingtoneURI);
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
    mp.start();
```